# Перевести дату в формат строки с кол-вом дней

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

В DataFrame есть столбец со значениями в следующем виде: `507 days 00:00:00`.

Мне нужно, чтобы на выходе было значение просто `507`. 
Попадалось `.strftime()`, но как применить его здесь не очень ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
df[“new”] = df[“timedelta”].dt.days
```

Если тип столбца строковый, то:

```
df[“new”] = pd.to_timedelta(df[“timedelta”]).dt.days
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вернуть только 507, то скорее это задача не `string -> date`, где нужен strptime, а просто парсинг строки. В таком случае, если во фразе всегда есть `days`  подойдет: `int(s.split('day')[0])` или чтобы исключить Exception в то будут две строки с проверкой результата split

```
res = s.split('day')
days = None if not len(res) else int(res[0])
```